# UITextField clearButton adjust inset of textfield when it appears

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that is center-aligned. I want to show the clear button when editing, so I use:

```
textfield.clearButtomMode = .whileEditing
```

The problem is that when the clear button appears, it moves the rest of the content in the textField to the left, and it's very jarring for someone who is typing.

Here's an illustration:

[image]

Any clue how to make it not do this, or make the clear button appear when the textField becomes first responder?

Comment: You can try increasing the textfield's width by that of the width of the clear button to offset the displacement of the text. or just set the clearButtonMode to .always

Comment: Make your own clear button, then add it to the textfield on `didBeginEditting`, it's totally not that hard, but beware that the move to the left is to prevent text to overlap with that button, and it's normal

Answer (score 3):

You could override `clearButtonRect(forBounds:)` to call the super implementation and then store the size of the clear button. Then, you can use that to update the text field's insets in `editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect)`. Let's say the button's width is 10, so if you add 10 point insets to the left and the right, the text will remain centered and there won't be any overlap with the button. The only downside is that the text will not be able to extend all the way to the left edge of the field due to the insets on that side.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield/1619600-clearbuttonrect
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield/1619589-editingrect